# Need help to prove that If $G$ is 2 - self centered graph. then how to prove that $G$ has at least $2n - 5$ edges, where $n\geq 5$.

Tags: graph-theory

If $G$ is 2 - self centered graph. then how to prove that $G$ has at least $2n - 5$ edges?
where $n\geq 5$.

I started by assuming if number of edges $\mid E\mid\leq 2n-6$
then there exist a vertex say $u$ such that $deg = 2$ otherwise if no such vertex exists then

$\mid E\mid\geq \frac{3n}{2}>2n-5$ (I am stucked here. How to prove this. Sincerely thanks for giving me time.)

Comment: Also posted to mathoverflow.net, where it ought to be closed sometime soon. So: what's a 2-self centered graph?

Comment: It probably means a self-centered graph (diameter=radius) of radius 2.

Comment: Since there are 2-self-centered graphs of arbitrarily large n, you will not be able to prove $\frac{3n}{2} \gt 2n-5$.

Answer (score 1):

I take it $n$ is the number of vertices. You might be interested in https://mathoverflow.net/questions/32301/examples-of-self-centered-graphs-with-large-radius. Among the things you'll find there is a link to a complete list of all self-centered graphs with diameter 2 that have minimum number of edges, and a link to a survey paper by Fred Buckley.

Answer (score 0):

i strongly recommend you to refere the following paper:
**Akiyama. j., Ando.K and Davis.D., Miscellaneous properties of equi eccentric graph in Convexity and Graph Theory. Proc. Conf. in Haifa Isreal-1981.**

Comment: Would you explain why this paper is useful for the Question? Answers are generally expected to address the Question being asked.